# How can I detect when an iAd has been dismissed?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

Newbie iOS programmer here, so apologies in advance if I can't see the answer right in front of my face. :)

I just added iAd to my sample app.  I'm running into a problem where when the user dismisses the ad, my numpad, that was displayed before clicking the ad, doesn't reappear.  I need the numpad to display after the ad has been dismissed.  Could you explain how I can capture the event for ad dismissal so that I can redisplay the numpad?  I have not been able to find a solution to this simple problem.

My app is very simple and was built to teach me iOS programming.  It's a speed converter app between miles per hour and kilometers per hour.  I have two fields for each of those data.  I had the numpad displayed at all times and it worked well, until I put in iAds.

I  noticed that when I click on the ad, the numpad is dismissed before the bigger add is displayed.  Then when the bigger ad is dismissed, I'm returned to my previous screen but the numpad is not displayed.  I can get the numpad to reappear when I click on either the miles or kilometer field.

On viewDidLoad, I initially have the numpad displaying with [mile becomeFirstResponder].  "mile" is the name of the miles per hour field.  If I knew how to capture  the user clicking on the ad to dismiss it, I can then reissue the  command: [mile becomeFirstResponder] to display the numpad.

I hope you understand my circumstance and what I'm trying to accomplish.  Maybe my problem is in a different area.  Is there another easier way to have the keyboard always displaying?

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

look to ADBannerViewDelegate and its property :

```
-(void) bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionDidFinish: